# How to get access token in spring oauth2

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Below is the security.xml file, which I am using to incorporate spring-security-oauth2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd ">


<!-- @author Nagesh.Chauhan(neel4soft@gmail.com) -->
<!-- This is default url to get a token from OAuth -->
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected 
    and what roles have access to them -->
<http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_APP" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>


<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>


<!-- This is simple authentication manager, with a hardcoded user/password 
    combination. We can replace this with a user defined service to get few users 
    credentials from DB -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="beingjavaguys" password="spring@java" authorities="ROLE_APP" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>


<!-- This defined token store, we have used inmemory tokenstore for now 
    but this can be changed to a user defined one -->
<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity 
    and other things -->
<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <!-- client -->
    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
        authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
        authorities="ROLE_APP" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

    <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
        authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
        secret="restapp" authorities="ROLE_APP" />

</oauth:client-details-service>

<sec:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the 
        http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

As of now for getting the token I have to make the request in below format:
[http://localhost:8080/SpringRestSecurityOauth/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=restapp&client_secret=restapp&username=beingjavaguys&password=spring@java]

Now I want the query paramters to be sent in json format like 
{
  "grant_type":"password",
  "client_id":"restapp",
  "client_secret":"restapp",
  "username":"beingjavaguys",
  "password":"spring@java"
}

What changes I have to do in spring-security.xml file so that I send query paramters in json?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that is not supported out of the box. To do that you would have to write your own REST service interface.

However the format you suggest also seems less 'REST-like' then the supported version (a GET request should be used for retrieving information). At least if you see it as retrieving and not creating a token.